# Pandas is sorting integer in a wierd way like string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sorting, pandas-groupby

Even when a column in a pandas **df** is **int**.. It is being sorted like a string or in a weird way.

```
n_frames  video        img
-----------------------------
1         Videos482    1.jpg
10        Videos482    2g.jpg
11        Videos482    2d.jpg
2         Videos482    1q.jpg
1         Videos484    234.jpg
100       Videos484    34.jpg
```

What I want is: **See the n_frames column**.

```
n_frames  video        img
-----------------------------
1         Videos482    1.jpg
2         Videos482    1t.jpg
10        Videos482    2g.jpg
11        Videos482    1q.jpg
1         Videos484    234.jpg
100       Videos484    34.jpg
```

When I check `df.dtypes` I get:

```
n_frames   int32
```

My code:

```
print(df.dtypes)
df = df.groupby('video')
df.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['n_frames']))
df.apply(lambda _df: _df.to_csv("rubbish.csv", index=False ))
```

So basically. I want to groupby the **video** keeping the **n_frames** in increasing accending order.
Upper data is small form of original.
Original>

```
n_frames,trainTest,classes,vdo_noext,img
1,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 1.jpg
10,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 10.jpg
100,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 100.jpg
101,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 101.jpg
102,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 102.jpg
103,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 103.jpg
104,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 104.jpg
105,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 105.jpg
106,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 106.jpg
107,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 107.jpg
108,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 108.jpg
109,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 109.jpg
11,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 11.jpg
110,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 110.jpg
111,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 111.jpg
112,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 112.jpg
113,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 113.jpg
114,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 114.jpg
115,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 115.jpg
116,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 116.jpg
117,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 117.jpg
118,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 118.jpg
119,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 119.jpg
12,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 12.jpg
120,1,1,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264,train/Normal/Normal_Videos482_x264@ 120.jpg
```

Update: **n_frames** column **dtype** *was never a string and integer even before I converted into int..* 
**Why is integer being sorted in that wierd way?**

Comment: For me working nice, also `df = df.sort_values(['video', 'n_frames'])` use unstead `df = df.groupby('video')
df.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['n_frames']))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say without the data to hand but I would switch the rows around like so:

```
df = df.groupby('video')
df['n_frames'] = df['n_frames'].astype(int)
df.apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(by=['n_frames']))
df.apply(lambda _df: _df.to_csv("rubbish.csv", index=False ))
```

In other words, change the data type after the `groupby`

Comment: Doesn't work.. I just checked that.. the column n_frames was always an integer...

Comment: Why are you not using `df.sort_values('n_frames', inplace=True)` instead of using a lambda function?

Comment: It throws out an weird error...** AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method **

Comment: Excel solved this problem in seconds.. Thanks anyways